# Sort collection by common ids and latest created date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose collection "travels" with data like below. In data there is 3 items with same `nUid` but `lastUpdateTime` is different for each entry.

```
[
  {
    _id: 5ffff2bc9698ce3514ef6d5a,
    nUid: 123456, 
    latitude: '19.154607',
    longitude: '72.936027', 
    name: 'abc1', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T07:26:51.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  }, 
  {
    _id: 5fffeca4794ca00ae85ee940, 
    nUid: 635241,
    latitude: '19.154620',
    longitude: '72.936087', 
    name: 'abc2', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T03:31:20.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5fffeca4794ca00ae85ee93f, 
    nUid: 123456,
    latitude: '19.154609',
    longitude: '72.936047', 
    name: 'abc1', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T09:20:23.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5ffff2bc9698ce3514ef6d59, 
    nUid: 123456,
    latitude: '19.154620',
    longitude: '72.936087', 
    name: 'abc1', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T10:38:20.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5ffff4610fd21902e02ac749, 
    nUid: 345262,
    latitude: '19.154620',
    longitude: '72.936087', 
    name: 'abc3', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T09:11:30.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5ffff4610fd21902e02ac748, 
    nUid: 635241,
    latitude: '19.154640',
    longitude: '72.936017', 
    name: 'abc2', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T04:30:10.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },
]
```

I want to sort data like common ids with latest `lastUpdateTime`

```
[
 {
    _id: 5ffff2bc9698ce3514ef6d59, 
    nUid: 123456,
    latitude: '19.154620',
    longitude: '72.936087', 
    name: 'abc1', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T10:38:20.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },  
  {
    _id: 5ffff4610fd21902e02ac748, 
    nUid: 635241,
    latitude: '19.154640',
    longitude: '72.936017', 
    name: 'abc2', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T04:30:10.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  }, 
  {
    _id: 5ffff4610fd21902e02ac749, 
    nUid: 345262,
    latitude: '19.154620',
    longitude: '72.936087', 
    name: 'abc3', 
    lastUpdateTime: 2021-01-14T09:11:30.000Z, 
    __v: 0
  },
]
```

Tried solution

```
const travelsQuery = Travels.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$nUid", result: { "$first": "$$ROOT" } } },
             { $sort: { lastUpdateTime: 1 } }]);  
const travelsData= await travelsQuery;

let travelsResult= travelsData.map((travel) => {
    return travel.result;
});
```

But not getting proper result, I got data with same ids but not sorted by `lastUpdateTime`, I tried `lastUpdateTime`: -1` also.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there are duplicate `_id`s, it should be unique.

Comment: in the solution you tried sorting ```lastLocationTime``` and in your question you are asking to sort by ```lastUpdateTime```

Comment: Sorry for that, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You copied the document into `result` so try:

```
const travelsQuery = Travels.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$nUid", result: { "$first": "$$ROOT" } } },
             { $sort: { "result.lastUpdateTime": 1 } }]);  
const travelsData= await travelsQuery;

let travelsResult= travelsData.map((travel) => {
    return travel.result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating `$first` to `$last` It's working as required :)

```
const travelsQuery = Travels.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$nUid", result: { "$last": "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $sort: { "result.lastUpdateTime": 1 } }]);  
const travelsData= await travelsQuery;

let travelsResult= travelsData.map((travel) => {
   return travel.result;
});
```

Comment: Is that not because you've used `result.lastUpdateTime` as I suggested in my answer and not because of changing `$first` to `$last`?

Comment: Your answer is right. But not working with `$first`. It's give a first document of sort instead of greatest lastUpdateTime result. I tried with `$last` It's give me a greatest lastUpdateTime result. Thank you. :)

Comment: Oh I see because it was using the first document, that has the lowest lastUpdateTime for the group.